# Theorem 3.3-1, Lemma 3.3-2, and Theorem 3.3-4 in Erwine Kreyszig's INTRODUCTORY FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS WITH APPLICATIONS: How to write these as one?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I'm trying to prepare some ancilliary material on  the following three results in sec. 3.3 in the book *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig:

(First, I'm giving verbatim the statements of Kreyszig. )

Theorem 3.3-1:

> Let $X$ be an inner product space and $M \neq \emptyset$ a convex subset which is complete (in the metric induced by the inner product). Then for every given $x \in X$ there exists a unique $y \in  M$ such that 
>   $$\delta \colon= \inf_{\tilde{y} \in M} \Vert x - \tilde{y} \Vert = \Vert x-y \Vert.$$

Lemma 3.3-2:

> In Theorem 3.3-1, let $M$ be a complete subspace $Y$ and $x \in X$ fixed. Then $z = x-y$ is orthogonal to $Y$.

Theorem 3.3-4:

> Let $Y$ be any closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. Then 
>   $$H = Y \oplus Z \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Z = Y^\perp.$$

Now my aim is to condense the above three results into one and make them easier and quicker to present. I feel that Kreyszig has repeated things rather superfluously. Am I right?

Here's how I have summarized the above three results into one:

Let $X$ be an inner product space, let $x \in X$, and let $M$ be a non-empty subset of $X$ such that $M$ is complete in the metric induced by the inner product, that is, the restriction to $M \times M$ of the metric 
$d$ on $X$ given by 
$$d(u,v) \colon= \sqrt{ \ \langle u-v, \  u-v \rangle \ } \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } u, v \in X.$$
Then we have the following:

(a) If $M$ is a convex subset, then there exists a unique element $y \in M$ such that 
$$D(x,M) = \Vert x - y \Vert;$$
that is, 
$$D(x,M) = \sqrt{ \ \langle x-y,\  x-y \rangle \  }.$$

(b) If $M$ is a vector subspace of $X$, then the unique 
element $y$ asserted in (a) also satisfies $ (x-y ) \perp M$, that is, 
$$\langle x-y, \ v \rangle = 0 \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ 
v \in M.$$

And, 
(c) if $X$ is a Hilbert space (i.e. if $X$ is complete 
in the metric induced by the inner product), if $M$ 
is a vector subspace of $X$, and if $M$ is closed with 
respect to the metric induced by the inner product, 
then there are unique elements $y \in M$ and $z \in X$ 
such that 
$$x = y+z \ \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \ \ \langle z, v \rangle = 0 \ \mbox{ for all } \ v \in M. $$

How good an attempt is it? Is it any improvement?

Any advice please? Should I stick with Kreyszig's plan? Or can I improve the above formulation any further?

Answer (score 1):

Your formulation seems compact to me. But here is one more thing that can be done. This formulation in not general but it surely is compact.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $M$ be a closed subspace of $H$. Then given any $x\in X$ there exists a unique $y\in M$ such that

(a) $\mathrm{dist}(x,M) = \|x-y\|$.

(b) $x-y\perp M$.

(c) $H = M\oplus M^{\perp}$.

Answer (score 0):

Can we modify (c) as

> If $Y$ be any non-empty **complete subspace** of an **inner-product space** $X$ then we can express $X$ as  $$X=Y \oplus Y^\perp$$

The Proof is similar to that in Kryeszig except for it is already stated $Y$ is complete. So given any $x \in X$ we can find $y \in Y$ such that $y$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ in $Y$ and $z=x-y \perp Y$ by (b). Therefore $x=y+z$ and proof of uniqueness is similar to that in Kreyszig.